# In Dr. Seuss's Bartholomew series, which book came first chronologically?

Tags: chronological-order, dr-seuss

Dr. Seuss wrote four books about Bartholomew, the young lad in the kingdom of Didd that presumably was named after the apostle.

But what is the chronological order of the books? Or did they take place in the order they were written?

Comment: I only know two books. 500 Hats, and Oobleck.  What are the other two?  For Hats and Oobleck, Hats is chronologically first.

Comment: There was also the Kings Stilts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only two books about the Kingdom of Didd:  *[The 500 Hats of Batholomew Cubbins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_500_Hats_of_Bartholomew_Cubbins)* and *[Bartholomew and the Oobleck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartholomew_and_the_Oobleck)*.  The first tells the story of how the protagonist becomes a page in the service of King Derwin, while the second tells of of a further adventure that Bartholomew has while in the king's service.  They take place in the order that they were written, having been published in 1938 and 1949, respectively.

*[The King's Stilts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_King%27s_Stilts)* (1939) takes place in a completely separate kingdom, Binn.  The geography of Binn is an important plot point, and it is quite different from that of Didd.  Stylistically, the book is quite similar to the Bartholomew Cubbins books (all are in prose instead of verse), with the young page Eric as the protagonist in the service of King Birtram.  However, they are not part of the same series.

There are no other Dr. Seuss books with similar structures.  FuzzyBoots' answer mentions *[The Seven Lady Godivas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Seven_Lady_Godivas)*, which (apart from a medieval setting) has very little in common with the Bartholomew Cubbins books.

Answer (score 2):

According to Wikpedia, *[The King's Stilts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_King%27s_Stilts)* is preceded by *[The 500 Hats of Bartholomew Cubbins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_500_Hats_of_Bartholomew_Cubbins)* and proceded by *[The Seven Lady Godivas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Seven_Lady_Godivas)*, although I believe that is the chronological order of publishing.

They also note *[Bartholomew and the  Oobleck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartholomew_and_the_Oobleck)* as being a sequel to *[The 500 Hats of Bartholomew Cubbins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WI7ScjB897I)*. So, my best guess is that the official order of the *Kingdom of Didd* books is:

1. *The 500 Hats of Bartholomew Cubbins*
2. *Bartholomew and the  Oobleck*
3. *The King's Stilts*
4. *The Seven Lady Godivas*